# The project file cannot be opened. Version 6.0.320 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.0.0 of MSBuild. The current available ver

Tags: .net

> **The project file cannot be opened. Version 6.0.320 of the .NET SDK requires at least version 17.0.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 16.11.2.50704. Change the .NET SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.
> **

I am trying to open a solution of an app. This solution was build in 2017. I purchased it in codecanyone. I followed the documentation and I installed everything. Then I face this error. please someone help me,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX0cX.png)

I tried to add the global .json file. After doing it, it says the dotnet SDK failed to locate.

I want to build this app with this source code.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Visual Studio is older than the minimum version supported by .NET SDK 6

Update Visual Studio to 2022

in [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/versioning-sdk-msbuild-vs) Document, you will find all supported Visual Studio versions by .NET SDK